# @yield placed at wrong place

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new to Laravel, and I'm trying to do a "modular" page for the first time. Everything was going fine, had my base layouts, which gets extended on my home page, have set up some sections/yields with no problem (content, title, etc) but one specific `@yield` keeps being rendered at the wrong place, I've put it inside my head file **(head.blade.php)**, which already have another `@yield` for the title, but that one keeps getting rendered inside the body. I tried doing some tests, and discovered that if I put my title `@yield` inside `<title></title>` it works OK, but if I put it outside the tag it is moved to the body.
Thats a normal Laravel way of working (`@yield` can't be by itself, only inside a tag) or something is wrong ?

**default.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        @include('includes.head')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header mdl-layout--no-desktop-drawer-button">
            @include('includes.nav')
            @yield('tools')
            <main class="mdl-layout__content">
                <div class="page-content">
                    @yield('content')
                </div>
            </main>
            @include('includes.footer')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**head.blade.php**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta name="description" content="XXXXXX">
<meta name="author" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXX">
<title>@yield('title')</title>  =====> Works normally if put here
@yield('title') =====> Rendered inside the body if put that way
<!-- jQuery 3.2.1 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Normalize CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
<!-- Dialog Polyfill -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dialog-polyfill.css">
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal browser behaviour. First of all you have to place all the things inside the right places. It's like you are trying eat some fat meat without fork and then crying that your hands in fat :)
You always have to define all tags that browsers expect. Title tag define that inside title of the page is located. `yield('title')` just means the name that you gave its for inserting there then. It looks like `id` in HTML.
Since you haven't described to browser **what** do you want to insert here it is trying to solve the problem and it's usually a placement all the things without needed tags in body (only if we are talking about omitting tags in the header).

Comment: Looks like I was being dumb.
If the @yield contains a valid html tag it will be placed at the right place

Comment: @IsraelPinheiro yield is just a command to put the text you want to named place in the brackets. It may contain HTML too, so it'll place your `<title>` from string you entered before. However, it's still necessary to set the `title` tag